# Как добавить скролл в выпадающем списке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input c типом "текст". Данное поле предназначено для поиска данных. То есть мы вводим например слово и внизу появляется список значений из базы данных. Проблема в том, что этот список может быть очень длинным. Как добавить скролл и показывать часть списка с возможностью его прокрутить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать списку максимально допустимую высоту +

`overflow: auto;` - вертикальная полоса прокрутки добавляется только при необходимости;

`overflow: scroll;` - всегда добавляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки.